# f(x) is a continious function and $f(0)=1$; $ f(7x) - f(x) = x$ then find$ f(42)$

Tags: functions

This type of question is solved using replacement property of functions. Here i replace x by 7x, one of the variable keeps increasing, so they don't cancel out.How should we approach such problem.

Comment: If we let $x=6$, we get $f(42)-f(6)=6$. Then let $x=6/7$ to get $f(6)-f(6/7)=6/7$. Continue in this manner and get a telescoping sum, which can be evaluated using the fact that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @Showhat, got it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we know that $f$ is continuous, then, we have $x$ converges to $0$ implies that $f(x)$ converges to $f(0)$. Since we know that $f(7x)=x+f(x)$, then, we have
\begin{align*}
f(42)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}f(x)+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{6}{7^{n}}=1+7=8.
\end{align*}